# Why a list of Dataframe not referring to the actual df

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a list of a data frame and I am assigning values to its columns at two different times.

```
list_df = [df1, df2, df3, df4]

for df in list_df:
   df = df[df.columns.interseciton(['Date', 'Amount', 'Name'],sort= False)]

***few line of code***

for df in list_df:
   df =  df.columns.to_series().map(col_fullform)
```

When I do this, I don't get the exact result. But when I do the column setting part as:

```
df1 = df1[df1.columns.interseciton(['Date', 'Amount', 'Name'],sort= False)]
df2 = df2[df2.columns.interseciton(['Date', 'Amount', 'Name'],sort= False)]
df3 = df3[df3.columns.interseciton(['Date', 'Amount', 'Name'],sort= False)]
df4 = df4[df4.columns.interseciton(['Date', 'Amount', 'Name'],sort= False)]


***Few line of code***

list_df = [df1, df2, df3, df4]
for df in list_df:
   df =  df.columns.to_series().map(col_fullform)
```

It gives me the correct format. So why is the list of df not referring to the actual df itself?

Comment: You are overriding what `df` points to in each iteration of the `for` loops. It's as if only the last iteration took place.

Comment: in the first iteration the df is ```df1``` right? so that the changes should saved to ```df1``` and so on.. In my case even the last df is not giving the correct format

Comment: No, that's not how variables work. In the first iteration `df` points to the same value as `df1`. You then compute a new value (`df[df.columns...`) and assign `df` to that value. `df1` still points to the old value. `df` will be overridden in the next iteration.

Comment: So what is my alternative if I want to do the same edit to different DFs?

Comment: `new_dataframes = [<operation> for df in list_df]`

Comment: you mean like this ?
```df = [df.columns.interseciton(['Date', 'Amount', 'Name'],sort= False) for df in list_df]``` ?? after this will the df1 to df4 will all be changed?

Comment: Yes, I mean like this. No, `df1` to `df4` still point to the same old dataframes. `df = [...]` creates a list of new dataframes. Feel free to ask follow up questions, but if you want to do me a favor, watch [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_AEJHKGk9ns) first.

Comment: What if I dont want a new list of df. I want to know if setting these changes to df1 to df4 possible or not.

Comment: You don't have to make a new list, you could mutate your old list_df via `list_df[:] = [<operation> for df in list_df]`. You cannot, however, select a subset columns from a dataframe in-place. That always returns a new dataframe. What you *could* do though, is to [drop](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html) the columns you don't want with `inplace=True`.